# Error 5560 The Find What text contains a Pattern Match expression which is not valid

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using a macro that searches and highlights paragraphs that are duplicated in a word document. I found it in a forum, the author of the post is macropod, which I think is part of this community.
The macro is the following:

```
Sub DemoA()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
Dim RngA As Range, RngB As Range, i As Long, j As Long, strFnd As String, strTmp As String
With ActiveDocument
  For i = 2 To .Paragraphs.Count - 1
    Set RngA = .Paragraphs(i - 1).Range
    Set RngB = .Range(.Paragraphs(i).Range.Start, .Range.End)
    With RngA
      strFnd = Trim(Split(.Text, vbCr)(0))
      If Len(strFnd) > 0 Then
        If .HighlightColorIndex <> wdYellow Then
          If Len(strFnd) > 255 Then
            strTmp = Left(strFnd, 255)
            With RngB
              With .Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .Text = strTmp
                .Format = True
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .MatchWildcards = True
                .Execute
                If .Found = True Then RngA.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
              End With
              Do While .Find.Found = True
                If Trim(Split(.Paragraphs.First.Range.Text, vbCr)(0)) = strFnd Then
                  .Paragraphs.First.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
                End If
                .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                .Find.Execute
              Loop
            End With
          Else
            With RngB.Find
              .ClearFormatting
              .Replacement.ClearFormatting
              .Text = strFnd
              .Replacement.Text = "^&"
              .Replacement.Highlight = True
              .Format = True
              .Forward = True
              .Wrap = wdFindStop
              .MatchWildcards = True
              .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
              If .Found = True Then RngA.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
            End With
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End With
    If i Mod 100 = 0 Then DoEvents
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But when I run it, I got the message  Run-time error '5560' The Find What text contains a Pattern Match expression which is not valid and when I click on "Debug", the command "execute" gets highlighted.

How can I fix this? I do need to check a 40.000 words document...

Thank you for your time and answers!

I tried to find a solution on internet but I was not able

Comment: I don’t know where you got that code from but it is different to the [original](https://www.msofficeforums.com/108279-post2.html) which has wildcards turned off.

Comment: Thank you for your help Timothy, I found it in a Microsoft community  post. However, I changed the macro with the one in the post you shared with me and now the macro run without errors, but still cannot identify duplicate paragraphs...  I did a test duplicating one paragraph in purpose but it did not get highlighted

Answer (score 0):

The code you obtained doesn't work when the paragraph length exceeds 255 characters. This is because the code compares the full text of the original paragraph to the shortened text of the found text. I have corrected this in the code below.

```
Sub FindDuplicateParas()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long, RngSrc As Range, RngFnd As Range
    Const Clr As Long = wdBrightGreen
    Dim eTime As Single
    eTime = Timer
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = Clr
    With ActiveDocument
        With .Range.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Forward = True
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Execute
        End With
        For i = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count
            If i Mod 100 = 0 Then DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set RngSrc = .Paragraphs(i).Range
            If RngSrc.HighlightColorIndex <> Clr Then
                Set RngFnd = .Range(.Paragraphs(i).Range.End, .Range.End)
                If Len(RngSrc.Text) < 256 Then
                    With RngFnd.Find
                        .Text = RngSrc.Text
                        .Replacement.Text = "^&"
                        .Replacement.Highlight = True
                        .Wrap = wdFindStop
                        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                    End With
                Else
                    With RngFnd
                        With .Find
                            .Text = Left(RngSrc.Text, 255)
                            .Wrap = wdFindStop
                            .Execute
                        End With
                        Do While .Find.Found
                            If RngSrc.Text = .Duplicate.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text Then
                                RngSrc.HighlightColorIndex = Clr
                                .Duplicate.Paragraphs(1).Range.HighlightColorIndex = Clr
                            End If
                            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                            .Find.Execute
                        Loop
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    ' Report time taken. Elapsed time calculation allows for execution to extend past midnight.
    MsgBox "Finished. Elapsed time: " & (Timer - eTime + 86400) Mod 86400 & " seconds."
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```